# Merge an array with an existing array php

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two array both containing data. I want to be able to add them together so that the information from the second array joins into the first array. Currently the array_merge that I am doing adds the second array to the end of the first one.

**Array 1**

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-13 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 16.11
            [4] => 80.56
            [5] => 96.67
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-13 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 1.23
            [4] => 50.69
            [5] => 14.24
        )
```

**Array 2**

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => TIME
            [1] => Lorem
            [2] => Ipsum
        )

[2] => Array
        (
            [0] => TIME
            [1] => Some
            [2] => Text

        )
```

How can I Merge the two arrays so the output becomes like below?

**Array 3**

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-13 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 16.11
            [4] => 80.56
            [5] => 96.67
            [6] => TIME
            [7] => Lorem
            [8] => Ipsum
        )
[2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-13 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 1.23
            [4] => 50.69
            [5] => 14.24
            [6] => TIME
            [7] => Some
            [8] => Text
        )
```

**What is currently happening**

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-14 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 16.11
            [4] => 80.56
            [5] => 96.67
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-14 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 1.23
            [4] => 50.69
            [5] => 14.24
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => TIME
            [1] => Lorem
            [2] => Ipsum
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => TIME
            [1] => Some
            [2] => Text
        )
```

I have tried `array_merge( $array1 , $array2 );` but that adds the second array to the end of the first one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Each array has 2 arrays in it, so merge each of those arrays with their counterparts, not the main array.

Comment: Have you tried [`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pretty forward to me, you simply `array_merge()` the elements of those two arrays:

```
<?php
$A = [
    1 => [
        '2017-07-13 00:00:00',
        'Foo',
        'Bar',
        16.11,
        80.56,
        96.67
    ],
    2 => [
        '2017-07-13 00:00:00',
        'Foo',
        'Bar',
        1.23,
        50.69,
        14.24
    ]
];
$B = [
    1 => [
        'TIME',
        'Lorem',
        'Ipsum'
    ],
    2 => [
        'TIME',
        'Some',
        'Text'
    ]
];

array_walk($B, function($values, $key) use (&$A) {
    $A[$key] = array_merge($A[$key], $values);
});
print_r($A);
```

The output of that obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-13 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 16.11
            [4] => 80.56
            [5] => 96.67
            [6] => TIME
            [7] => Lorem
            [8] => Ipsum
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-13 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 1.23
            [4] => 50.69
            [5] => 14.24
            [6] => TIME
            [7] => Some
            [8] => Text
        )
)
```

---

UPDATE:

In the comment below you ask if this approach can be generalized to merge an arbitrary number of arrays. Sure that is possible, you just add another iteration layer:

```
<?php
$target = [
    1 => ['2017-07-13 00:00:00', 'Foo', 'Bar', 16.11, 80.56, 96.67],
    2 => ['2017-07-13 00:00:00', 'Foo', 'Bar', 1.23, 50.69, 14.24]
];
$sources = [
    'B' => [
        1 => ['TIME', 'Lorem', 'Ipsum'],
        2 => ['TIME', 'Some', 'Text']
    ],
    'C' => [
        1 => ['C1a', 'C1b'],
        2 => ['C2a', 'C2b', 'C2b']
    ]
];

array_walk($sources, function($source) use (&$target) {
    array_walk($source, function($values, $key) use (&$target) {
        $target[$key] = array_merge($target[$key], $values);
    });
});
print_r($target);
```

This variant produces that output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-13 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 16.11
            [4] => 80.56
            [5] => 96.67
            [6] => TIME
            [7] => Lorem
            [8] => Ipsum
            [9] => C1a
            [10] => C1b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-07-13 00:00:00
            [1] => Foo
            [2] => Bar
            [3] => 1.23
            [4] => 50.69
            [5] => 14.24
            [6] => TIME
            [7] => Some
            [8] => Text
            [9] => C2a
            [10] => C2b
            [11] => C2b
        )

)
```

Comment: Genius. Is this adaptable if I have more than 2 arrays? if I wanted to merge 3 arrays together into one?

Comment: Sure, I added a variant for that as an UPDATE to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this with [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)?

> array_merge_recursive() merges the elements of one or more arrays
>   together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the
>   previous one. It returns the resulting array.

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($first_array, $second_array);
```

**EDIT:** If array_merge_recursive doesn't work for you then try this https://eval.in/838950

```
<?php
$first_array = [
    1 => [
        '2017-07-13 00:00:00',
        'Foo',
        'Bar',
        16.11,
        80.56,
        96.67
    ],
    2 => [
        '2017-07-13 00:00:00',
        'Foo',
        'Bar',
        1.23,
        50.69,
        14.24
    ]
];
$second_array = [
    1 => [
        'TIME',
        'Lorem',
        'Ipsum'
    ],
    2 => [
        'TIME',
        'Some',
        'Text'
    ]
];

foreach($second_array as $k=>$v){
 $first_array[$k] = array_merge($frist_array[$k],$v);
}


 print '<pre>';
 /*print_r(array_merge_recursive($first_array,$second_array));*/      
 print_r($frist_array);
```

Comment: I tried this but It did not work, See edited question for the output I am getting with array_merge() and array_merge_recursive()

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a multi dimensional array?

That's pretty easy.

```
$new_array[] = $array_1;
$new_array[] = $array_2;
```

Comment: Try your own code. You will see that it does _not_ produce the output as described in the question.

Comment: You are right, I got ahead of myself, and didn't finish the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach:

```
    $array1 = [
        [1,2,3,4],
        [6,7,8,9]
    ];
    $array2 = [
        ['a','b'],
        ['c', 'd']
    ];
    $array3 = [];
    foreach (range(0, max(count($array1), count($array2))-1) as $i) {
        $part1 = isset($array1[$i]) ? $array1[$i] : [];
        $part2 = isset($array2[$i]) ? $array2[$i] : [];
        $array3[] = array_merge($part1, $part2);
    }
```